# draw a row of circles positioned in x and y coordinates using a loop in vb net

Tags: vb.net

I use the following code to draw a row of circles having a diameter D and positioned in x and y coordinates (user control). The number of circles in the row depends on a variable N.

```
Dim rectangle1, rectangle2, rectangle3, rectangle4, rectangle5, 
rectangle6,......... as rectangle 
Dim XR1, XR2, XR3, XR4, XR5, XR6,........YR1, YR2, YR3, YR4, YR5,   
YR6,......... 
as Single
XR1 = XPxf(0)       ' Function XPxf (k)
XR2 = XPxf(1)
XR3 = XPxf(2)
XR4 = XPxf(3)
' Etc...
YR1 = XPyf(0)       ' Function YPyf (k)
YR2 = XPyf(1)
YR3 = XPyf(2)
YR4 = XPyf(3)
' Etc...
If N = 4 Then
rectangle1 = New Rectangle(XR1, YR1, D, D)
rectangle2 = New Rectangle(XR2, YR2, D, D)
rectangle3 = New Rectangle(XR3, YR3, D, D)
rectangle4 = New Rectangle(XR4, YR4, D, D)
G.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Color.White, 3), rectangle1)
G.DrawRectangle(Pens.Transparent, rectangle1)
G.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Color.White, 3), rectangle2)
G.DrawRectangle(Pens.Transparent, rectangle2)
G.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Color.White, 3), rectangle
G.DrawRectangle(Pens.Transparent, rectangle3)
G.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Color.White, 3), rectangle4)
G.DrawRectangle(Pens.Transparent, rectangle4) 
ElseIf N13 = 6 Then
rectangle1 = New Rectangle(XR1, YR1, D1, D2)
rectangle2 = New Rectangle(XR2, YR2, D1, D2)
rectangle3 = New Rectangle(XR3, YR3, D1, D2)
' Etc......
```

I am trying to make it shorter by using a loop, but I am not familiar at all with it. After several attempts the following code just allows me to get the circles on top of each others at the left upper corner of the screen , meaning that x and y are not taken into account.

```
If N = 4 Then
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim k As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To 3
        Dim rect(i) As Rectangle
        Dim XPxf(k), YPyf(k) As Single
        rect(i) = New Rectangle(XPxf(k), XPyf(k), D, D)
        G.DrawRectangle(Pens.Transparent, rect(i))
        G.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Color.White, 3), rect(i))
        k = i
        i += 1
    Next
Elseif N = 6 Then
  ' Etc...
```

Thanks in advance for any help on that coordinate issue.

**UPDATED TO ADD:**

@ Lars: Debugging does not indicate any error.

@ Topshot: I have been trying several ways from your suggestion but the drawings still remain in the upper left corner of the screen. To make it easier, here is a simplified program including a module with 2 functions for you to test your solution.

In module:

```
Public Function XPxf(ByVal k As Integer) As Single
    XPxf = Form1.TextBox1.Text + k * 20
End Function

Public Function XPyf(ByVal k As Integer) As Single
    Dim Ryf As Single
    If XPxf(k) > 200 Then
        Ryf = 100
    ElseIf XPxf(k) > 400 Then
        Ryf = 200
    ElseIf XPxf(k) > 600 Then
        Ryf = 300
    End If
    Return Ryf
    Form1.TextBox4.Text = Ryf
End Function
```

In form1:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
```

In form2:

```
Private Sub form2_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    Dim G As Graphics
    G = Me.CreateGraphics
    Dim N = Val(Form1.TextBox2.Text)
    Dim D = Val(Form1.TextBox3.Text)
    Try
        For i As Integer = 1 To N
            Dim k As Integer = i - 1
            Dim rect(i) As Rectangle
            Dim XPxf(k) As Single
            Dim XPyf(k) As Single

            rect(i) = New Rectangle(XPxf(k), XPyf(k), D, D)
            G.DrawRectangle(Pens.Transparent, rect(i))
            G.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Color.Black, 3), rect(i))
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Put a stop debugger on your line of code and run your program.  When it hits that line and stops, walk through the lines step by step and examine the variables as they get updated.  Remove the `i += 1` line since it's not needed, it's already incrementing by the the loop.  The k variable looks needless since it's always equal to i.  Just use i.  If you have to declare six rectangles or more, it's probably better to use a List of Rectangles instead.

Comment: As I am not familiar with Stackoverflow and wanted to add codes, I used the "post an answer" rubric since I  could not do it with the "add comment".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be close but without all your code I can't test it.

```
Dim rect(N) As Rectangle
'Dim XPxf(N - 1) As Integer
'Dim YPyf(N - 1) As Integer
Dim k As Integer = 0
For i = 1 To N
    rect(i) = New Rectangle(XPxf(k), XPyf(k), D, D)
    G.DrawRectangle(Pens.Transparent, rect(i))
    G.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Color.White, 3), rect(i))
    k = i
Next
```

Made it so you didn't need a bunch of If statements for different values of N. You should really turn Option Strict ON since you had several conversions (i.e., Rectangle function takes integers not single).

EDIT: Remove or comment out the 2 lines I did above and it will work. However, for larger values in TextBox1, it draws first circle and then makes a second line so you need to fix your calculations. You also need to move `Form1.TextBox4.Text = Ryf` above the `Return Ryf` line.

Comment: As I am not familiar with Stackoverflow and wanted to add codes, I used the "post an answer" rubric since I  could not do it with the "add comment".

Comment: @Dom My edit will now work. However, you should really turn **Option Strict ON** to get rid of all your potential conversion issues aside from the fact it is good coding practice.

Comment: Great, here it also works. I have turned option strict on and will keep your recommendation in mind. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dom Glad it worked. Please select my answer as correct then. :)